# What is a cheap way to measure co2 or o2 level in air?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making an air purifier which also increases o2 level as a school project but facing some difficulties. I plan to run the purifier whenever the co2 level is higher than usual or o2 level is lesser than usual but the sensor available in the market are quite expensive. So is there any cheaper alternative or any other method to detect a change in concentration?

Comment: why are you asking that question on an Arduino website? .... it has nothing to do with Arduinos ...... you may have better luck at a chemistry site

Answer (score 5):

Well, MQ 135 sensor is very cheap general air quality measurement device. It costs around 3$. There is another similar on AliExpress, not even worth mentioning. What is your budget? Gravity from Adafruit seems proper, yet it is at 56$. One that seems actually serious is K30 sensor, but that is around 100$. That 3$ stuff is general, and will work when temperature is constant, humidity is constant and Mars is aligned with Venus.

I think 56$ is ok if they want to have something proper. Remember that you get what you pay for.